# Failed to find any OpenCL platforms in cpp

Tags: c++, gpu, opencl

I am trying to execute this hello world code from opencl programming guide. It showing "Failed to find any OpenCL platforms.". I am compiling the source with g++ -std=c++0x HelloWorld.cpp -o main.out -l OpenCL.
Why it showing "Failed to find any OpenCL platforms. Failed to create OpenCL context."

```
cl_context CreateContext()
{
    cl_int errNum;
    cl_uint numPlatforms;
    cl_platform_id firstPlatformId;
    cl_context context = NULL;

    // First, select an OpenCL platform to run on.  For this example, we
    // simply choose the first available platform.  Normally, you would
    // query for all available platforms and select the most appropriate one.
    errNum = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &firstPlatformId, &numPlatforms);

    if (errNum != CL_SUCCESS || numPlatforms <= 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to find any OpenCL platforms." << std::endl;
        return NULL;
    }

    // Next, create an OpenCL context on the platform.  Attempt to
    // create a GPU-based context, and if that fails, try to create
    // a CPU-based context.
    cl_context_properties contextProperties[] =
    {
        CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM,
        (cl_context_properties)firstPlatformId,
        0
    };
    context = clCreateContextFromType(contextProperties, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU,
                                      NULL, NULL, &errNum);
    if (errNum != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        std::cout << "Could not create GPU context, trying CPU..." << std::endl;
        context = clCreateContextFromType(contextProperties, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU,
                                          NULL, NULL, &errNum);
        if (errNum != CL_SUCCESS)
        {
            std::cerr << "Failed to create an OpenCL GPU or CPU context." << std::endl;
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    return context;
}
```

Comment: You should probably check the value of `errNum` to see what went wrong.

Comment: You need both the OpenCL development libraries **and** an OpenCL runtime and those usually come from different packets (assuming you are running some Linux distro).

Comment: error number is -1001.

Comment: I am install packages with        sudo apt update        sudo apt install ocl-icd-opencl-dev. and it not showing any error when I am exicuting opencl C program but cpp program showing this error.

Comment: can anyone help me?